# Grails - Criteria, exclusive selection

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, eager-loading

I have a domain class containing a 1 to Many relationship. One `CreditProvider` can have Many `Rate`s.
I would like to select all the `CreditProvider`s that was not rated today with a criteria query (or other if not possible this way), and I am stuck.

Here is the query to retrieve all the CreditProviders rated today:

```
def criteria = CreditProvider.createCriteria()
def forgottenCreditProvidersToday = criteria.list {
                rates {
                        between('dateCreated', dateTodayAtMidnight, dateTodayAndNow)
                }
            }
}
```

How could I select the opposite, that is to say the `CreditProviders` that were not yet rated today ? 
Also, why do I not manage to eagerly fetch the rates this way:

```
fetchMode("rates", FM.EAGER)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

---

**EDIT:**
Provisory solution:

```
def criteria = CreditProvider.createCriteria()

        def creditProvidersRatedToday = criteria.list {
            rates {
                    gt('dateCreated', dateTodayAtMidnight)
        }
    order "originalName", "asc"
}
def creditProviders = CreditProvider.findAll()
```

creditProviders.removeAll(creditProvidersRatedToday)

I am open to any more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In resulting SQL, this would require subquery like

```
select * from credit_provider
inner join rates on rates.credit_provider_id = credit_provider.id
where not exists 
  (select id from rates where dateCreated between ? and ?)
```

Grails Criteria don't support subqueries. Though, [HQL does support subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) - you can translate this into HQL.

Answer (score -2):

the opposite is usually achieved by "not", e.g.

```
def criteria = CreditProvider.createCriteria()
def forgottenCreditProvidersToday = criteria.list {
    rates {
        not {
            between('dateCreated', dateTodayAtMidnight, dateTodayAndNow)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wrong - as there are many `Rate`s for a `CreditProvider`, there probably will be `Rate`s outside the range, though `CreditProvider` was rated today.